# Seeking outline coordinates of bodies of water (lakes, rivers, ponds) for country?

Tags: data, rivers, lakes

I'm in need of acquiring the coordinates of the outlines of all the water bodies inside a country, with the exception of "Sea" or "Ocean" water. Right now, I'm manually outlining the lakes and rivers but it is not a sustainable solution for the magnitude of the research I'm doing.

Even if I can only obtain the data of Lakes or Rivers, that would be a great start. I'm specifically interested in the countries of Malaysia, Brazil and the Dominican Republic.

My situation brings me to the question of, where does google obtain its data and are they available?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user of this particular SE site be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.  I think you should focus this question on just obtaining the Lakes and Rivers of one country (an answer may well provide a world-wide source anyway) and research where Google gets its data separately.

Answer (score 2):

Pick one:

- [GLWD](http://www.worldwildlife.org/pages/global-lakes-and-wetlands-database)
- [SRTM Water Bodies](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/srtm_water_body_dataset)
- [ESRI World Water Bodies](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e750071279bf450cbd510454a80f2e63)
- [GLCF Global Inland Water](http://glcf.umd.edu/data/watercover/)

Comment: Natural Earth website