# Mapping latitude-longitude to body of water

Tags: gps

Is there a web service or dataset making it possible to map a latitude-longitude pair to the name of a body of water such as the name of an ocean, or large sea or lake? I am thinking of something akin to, say, http://services.gisgraphy.com/public/geocoding.html or one of the datasets available from thematicmapping.org for countries.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185159/how-can-i-get-the-outline-coordinates-of-bodies-of-water-in-a-country-lakes-r.com) may lead you to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) is always a good bet for this sort of query. In this case I'd use their [findNearBy service](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearby)

Something like:

```
http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat=50.3&lng=0&username=demo&fclass=H
```

should do it.